# Node script to import reddit JSON won't work

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I want to import the reddit json thread into my mongodb local server, so I can begin analyzing it. Please help me out.

> app.js file below

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , request = require('request');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/trasmatter', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
request('https://www.reddit.com/r/Seattle/comments/3e0q5u/why_metro_matters_infographic/.json', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(body);

        var stories = obj.data.children.map(function (story) { return story.data; });

        db.collection('reddit').insert(stories, function (err, data) {
                if(err) throw err;

                console.dir(data);

                db.close();
        });
    }
});
});
```

> Console error after running 'node app.js'

```
app.js:11
            var stories = obj.data.children.map(function (story) { return sto
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/Users/yay/code/pulley/app.js:11:35)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/yay/code/pulley/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/yay/code/pulley/node_modules/request/request.js:1057:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/yay/code/pulley/node_modules/request/request.js:1003:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

> Another script file that works successfully. (I just plugged in
>   another link and change localhost link)

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
     , request = require('request');

   MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/course', function(err, db) {
       if(err) throw err;

       request('http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/.json', function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              var obj = JSON.parse(body);

             var stories = obj.data.children.map(function (story) { return story.data; });

              db.collection('reddit').insert(stories, function (err, data) {
                      if(err) throw err;

                      console.dir(data);

                      db.close();
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

On your second example, when requesting `http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/.json` the JSON result is an object:

```
{"kind":"stuff","data":{}}
```

But the first request result to an array of objects :

```
[{"kind":"stuff", "data":{}}, {"kind":"stuff","data":{}}]
```

In order to get your data, you need a loop or specify which object you want :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(obj[0].data); // for example
```

Comment: I got a pretty unique console log. { modhash: '',
  children: [ { kind: 't3', data: [Object] } ],
  after: null,
  before: null }
/Users/yay/code/pulleykingcounty/pulley/app.js:12
            var stories = obj.data.children.map(function (story) { return stor
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/Users/yay/code/pulleykingcounty/pulley/app.js:12:35)

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(obj[1].data); is an entirely different error.

Comment: I want to be able to index into children": [{"kind": "t3", "data": {"domain": "wired.com", "banned_by":

Comment: `var stories = obj.data.children.map()` same problem here, you try to access to obj as an object, but it's an array...

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to this guy https://github.com/loganfranken

It looks like https://www.reddit.com/r/Seattle/comments/3e0q5u/why_metro_matters_infographic/.json returns an array as the top-level JSON element, so I think changing this:

`obj.data.children`

To this:

`obj[1].data.children`

Should do the trick.